# $_REQUEST на javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Мне надо сделать проверку request но на javascript.
Написал такой скрипт, но проверка не работает.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   switch( document.location+'' ){
    case '?calc=Y':
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a#calc').click();
    });
    break;
   </script>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить после break; закрывающую фигурную скобку. 
Для проверки запроса для данного пути - используют **document.location.search** 
Для проверки запроса от корня **document.location.pathname + document.location.search**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   switch( document.location.search ){
        case '?calc=Y':
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a#calc').click();
        });
        break;
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Для начала, нехило бы закрывать открытые конструкции, да, я про `switch(){`
2. Стоит помнить, что document.location содержит весь адрес из адресной строки. При помощи, например, replace можно избавиться от всего лишнего:

   var loc = (document.location+'');
   loc = loc.replace(/^([^?]+)/,'');

Answer (score 0):

```
if(/(\?|&)calc=Y/i.test(location.href)){
    // в строке адреса фигурирует ?calc=Y или &calc=Y
}
```

Только это не `$_REQUEST`, а `$_GET`. `$_POST` вы js'ом не отловите.